# Why I need an Xorg login to use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Hyper-V windows 10, and How Do I Create Those Credentials

Tags: xorg

I created a Virtual Machine with Hyper-V in Windows 10. However, when Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed and it asked to connect. I connected, then it went thru the configuration phase, at that, I keep running into the login window with Xorg. I don't have Xorg credentials. I noticed you can select different login methods, but I am new to UBUNTU 18.04 LTS or any ubuntu flavor. Can I get past this? Please!

Comment: Login with the username and password you created under installation

Comment: I keep using that, and it doesn't login...

Comment: nevermind, I was using the wrong username...

Answer (score 4):

It's a feature of the enhanced session mode of Hyper-V. I guess u've created using the Quick Create. It's normal to see Xorg sign in. It's using a RDP. But in return you get full screen Ubuntu and drive and clipboard sharing which are otherwise difficult to set up.

Comment: Hover Craft, Niko Craft here :) I know its been 4 years since you posted. But I'm having this same issue, I login with correct credentials and I am logged in, no errors or anything, I did test with wrong password and got an error. Once I am "logged in" all I see is the blueish/greenish background, I can see the mouse pointer but right clicking does nothing, no icons and no usual Ubuntu desktop look. Can this Xorg be disabled afterwards? I did create using Quick Setup. If you recommend I still go with Xorg, how do I make it work? Best regards /Craft